# how comparing value from channel in Go

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

I have two channels, first give me some strings, which I need filter to same values, then result need sent to second channel

```
func main() {
    c := make(chan string, 5)
    o := make(chan string, 5)
    arr := []string{"aa", "ab", "ab", "bb", "bb", "ba", "cc"}
    for _, v := range arr {
        c <- v
        go removeDuplicates(c, o)
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        fmt.Println("output: ", <-o)
    }
}

func removeDuplicates(cIn, cOut chan string) {
   last := ""
   for cur, isOpen := <-cIn; isOpen; {
      if cur != last {
        fmt.Printf("val: %s, last: %s\n", cur, last) 
        last = cur
        cOut <- cur
        //close(cOut)
      }
   }
}
```

I try save previous value to "last" variable, but when I run the program, "last" is empty

```
val: aa, last: 
output:  aa
val: ab, last: 
output:  ab
val: ab, last:
```

also I don't know when and which channels need to be closed in this situation.
Thank you for your help and attention

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: It would be good if you can add a small example of same with a playground link

Comment: `last = <- cur` maybe?

Comment: sorry guys, this is a test task, I don't see all the code myself, I tried to reproduce it  in playground, but it generally gave an error: "timeout running program" https://play.golang.org/p/MpUyPkkP0XF

Comment: @SaeedEntezari No `cur` is not a `chan string` but `string`. Hence you can't do `<-cur`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### First fixing `removeDuplicates()`

The problem is that you have an empty post statement in your [`for` statement](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements):

```
for cur, isOpen := <-cIn; isOpen; {
    // ..
}
```

So you receive once from the `cIn` channel, but you never receive more, you do nothing in the post statement, so you just repeat the loop body, endlessly.

Once the loop body is executed, you have to receive again:

```
for cur, isOpen := <-cIn; isOpen; cur, isOpen = <-cIn {
    // ..
}
```

With this, output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_Aql8VyAQEF)):

```
val: aa, last: 
output:  aa
val: ab, last: aa
output:  ab
val: ab, last: 
output:  ab
val: bb, last: ab
output:  bb
val: bb, last: 
output:  bb
val: ba, last: ab
output:  ba
val: cc, last: 
output:  cc
```

But best would be to use `for range` over the channel:

```
for cur := range cIn {
    if cur != last {
        fmt.Printf("val: %s, last: %s\n", cur, last)
        last = cur
        cOut <- cur
    }
}
```

This outputs the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/bzVhM4lLWFr).

#### Now on to fixing the `main()`

We see "invalid" output, values in output are still duplicated.

This is because you launch multiple goroutines running `removeDuplicates()`. This is bad because the values sent on the input channel will be received by multiple goroutines, and if the duplicated values are not received by one, they can still be detected as unique, hence the same value will be sent more than once to the output.

Have a single producer sending all values on the input channel, and once all values were sent, close the channel.

Have a single goroutine filtering the values, using `for range`, and once the loop exits (all input values are consumed), close the output channel.

And have a single goroutine receive values from the output channel, using `for range`, so you can eliminate that ugly `time.Sleep`:

```
func main() {
    c := make(chan string, 5)
    o := make(chan string, 5)

    go func() {
        arr := []string{"aa", "ab", "ab", "bb", "bb", "ba", "cc"}
        for _, v := range arr {
            c <- v
        }
        close(c)
    }()

    go removeDuplicates(c, o)

    for v := range o {
        fmt.Println("output: ", v)
    }
}

func removeDuplicates(cIn chan string, cOut chan string) {
    last := ""
    for cur := range cIn {
        if cur != last {
            fmt.Printf("val: %s, last: %s\n", cur, last)
            last = cur
            cOut <- cur
        }
    }
    close(cOut)
}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/e2C1-gl8b5m)):

```
val: aa, last: 
val: ab, last: aa
val: bb, last: ab
val: ba, last: bb
val: cc, last: ba
output:  aa
output:  ab
output:  bb
output:  ba
output:  cc
```

Answer (score 1):

I've commented the code so that you can understand. Please refer the following code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var (
        c  = make(chan string, 1)
        o  = make(chan string, 1)
        wg = sync.WaitGroup{}
    )

    stream := []string{"aa", "ab", "ab", "bb", "bb", "ba", "cc"}

    wg.Add(1)
    // Wait until all the values are received
    defer wg.Wait()
    // Getter receives the filtered out stream
    go getter(o, &wg)

    // Removes duplicates from the stream
    go removeDuplicates(c, o)

    // Send elems to removeDuplicates
    for _, elem := range stream {
        c <- elem
    }
    // Close the channel
    close(c)
}

// getter recieves the filtered out elements
func getter(cOut <-chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for val := range cOut {
        fmt.Println("Output: ", val)
    }
}

// removeDuplicates removes the adjacent duplicates
func removeDuplicates(cIn chan string, cOut chan string) {
    var last string
    for cur := range cIn {
        if cur != last {
            fmt.Printf("val: %s, last: %s\n", cur, last)
            last = cur
            cOut <- cur
        }
    }
    close(cOut)
}
```

Comment: Thank you too @shmsr, this is test task where I can change only removeDuplicates func, but I realy greatful for your help